PYTHON Code Execution Error - frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1165)_find_and_load()?
I get the following Error when executing this PYTHON Code on MAC OS 10.15(CATALINA).  I am coding PYTHON 3.11 with IDLE Shell.
Python 3.11.4 (v3.11.4:d2340ef257, Jun  6 2023, 19:15:51) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
 
================ RESTART: /Users/bretontm/PYTHON KEYBOARD Cntrl.py ===============
> /Users/bretontm/PYTHON KEYBOARD Cntrl.py <module>()
-> import termios, sys
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1165)_find_and_load()
(Pdb) 

I am guessing that PYTHON IDLE Environment can not find either the termios or sys module.  My question is how do I fix it?  Is the problem a missing PATH NAME or Library Module?
Thanks Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated
Executed these PYTHON LINES of CODE
import termios, sys
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()

and then the code goes SOUTH w this Err:
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1165)_find_and_load()

, based on JasonHarper Comments, I deleted the import pdb and pdb.set_trace().  I then executed this code:

!/usr/bin/env python3
 
import sys
import time
import tty
import termios
 
of = open('copyTEXTFILE_OUTPUT01.txt', 'w')
 
def get_key():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setcbreak(fd)
        return sys.stdin.read(1)
 
    finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
            
def print_ascii(key):
    print(f"ASCII value of '{key}': {ord(key)}")
 
print("Press any key (Esc to exit):")
 
while True:
    key = get_key()
    if key == 'q':
       print("DONE")
       quit()
    if key == '\x1b' or key == '\x0d':  # check for Escape key
LN#33        hexkey = hex(key)
        print(f"EXIT/BREAK value of '{key}': {ord(key)}")
        break
    print_ascii(key)
 
print("DONE")
 
quit()


he PYTHON CODE executed correctly (see below) until,  I pushed the ESC KEY.  So that’s a different  problem.  However, if I insert import pdb  and pdb.set.trace(), the code fails as explained in initial post.
So the question is how do I make import pdb and pdb.set.trace() work so I can step through my code?  Thanks for taking time to help me.  Appreciate it.
Last login: Thu Jul 25 19:09:25 on ttys001
MACMini-2 ~ % /var/folders/wp/9s_gr55d2qj254n9sv8qr4bc0000gn/T/com.barebones.bbedit/com.barebones.bbedit-743794824.687-sh.sh ; exit;
Press any key (Esc to exit):
ASCII value of 'n': 110
ASCII value of 'p': 112
ASCII value of 'h': 104
ASCII value of 'T': 84
ASCII value of 'h': 104
ASCII value of 'o': 111
ASCII value of 'n': 110
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mhotto/TERMIOSScratch.py", line 33, in 
hexkey = hex(key)
^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
[Process completed]

There is nothing wrong with your termios or sys modules - if there was, you would have gotten an error before reaching the code involving pdb.  And the thing you are referring to as an error is simply the Python debugger prompt, which you are seeing because you explicitly told Python to enter the debugger - what were you expecting pdb.set_trace() to do, otherwise?

Turned-Off Debugger Code

So after testing the code you wrote on my machine and it worked I have concluded that perhaps it may be an issue with invalid modules or bugged modules to be honest because it is working perfectly fine on my machine so verify that those modules exist and comment out line 1 then run it then uncomment it and comment line 2 and then see which module was causing the problem or perhaps you don’t actually have it installed but more than likely after making the following change your software should run

#import termios, sys
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()


And if that fixes it that means termios/sys or both are missing or are broken for some reason

If it's working fine on your machine and you don't have a precise solution, I'd rather you just flag the post instead of trying to answer it...

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts
